# arithmetic progression by Dirichlet

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The arithmetic progression $a_N=(p-1)N+1$ contains infinitely many primes $q$ by Dirichlet. I have searched this part in wiki, but I din't get any relevant proof. Can any one prove it how $a_N$ contains infinitely many primes and what is Dirichlet proof? please explain.

Comment: There are many places it is done, for example Apostol's book on Analytic Number Theory. For the case $cn+1$, which is the one you are interested in, there is also a proof that does not use Analytic Number Theory. But it is not easy. Neither proof can, I think, be usefully summarized in an MSE answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas! I don't have the book. Any how, if you can summarize this part, I will be happy. Please do it.

Comment: Searching will show that there are many complete (and lengthy!) proofs on the Internet. Here is [the first one I bumped into.](http://people.csail.mit.edu/kuat/courses/dirichlet.pdf) I do not know how clear it is, mentioned Apostol because I am familiar with it and it is good.

Comment: @AndréNicolas! Thanks a lot. but nothing going in my mind.

Comment: You are welcome. The result is difficult, unless you have a fairly considerable amount of background knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

He used the L-function. You can read about it on this page - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function

It says that he introduced them to prove his theorem.